# Merging results of two different qualifier queries in SPARQL

Tags: sparql, wikidata, wikidata-query-service, wikibase

I can't come up with the right way to describe my problem, so I'll just show it. I want to find towns (aka seats) in two subsidiary regions (subprovinces aka sancaks and districts aka kazas) of each province (aka vilayet) in a wikibase I've made of Ottoman placenames.

I have a query that works for the [subprovinces](https://ottgaz.org/query/index.html#%23%20Map%20of%20every%20sancak%20seat%20within%20each%20vilayet%2C%20in%20the%20year%201900.%20Labels%20in%20Ottoman%20Turkish.%20To%20search%20a%20different%20year%2C%20change%20both%20dates%20in%20line%2024.%0A%23defaultView%3AMap%7B%22layer%22%3A%22%3FvilayetLabel%22%2C%22hide%22%3A%22%3Fcoord%22%7D%0APREFIX%20og%3A%20%3Chttps%3A%2F%2Fottgaz.org%2Fentity%2F%3E%0APREFIX%20ogs%3A%20%3Chttps%3A%2F%2Fottgaz.org%2Fentity%2Fstatement%2F%3E%0APREFIX%20ogv%3A%20%3Chttps%3A%2F%2Fottgaz.org%2Fvalue%2F%3E%0APREFIX%20ogt%3A%20%3Chttps%3A%2F%2Fottgaz.org%2Fprop%2Fdirect%2F%3E%0APREFIX%20ogp%3A%20%3Chttps%3A%2F%2Fottgaz.org%2Fprop%2F%3E%0APREFIX%20ogps%3A%20%3Chttps%3A%2F%2Fottgaz.org%2Fprop%2Fstatement%2F%3E%0APREFIX%20ogpq%3A%20%3Chttps%3A%2F%2Fottgaz.org%2Fprop%2Fqualifier%2F%3E%0A%0ASELECT%20%20%3FvilayetLabel%20%3FsancakSeat_ota%20%3FsancakSeat%20%3Fcoord%20%3FsancakSeatLabel%20%0AWHERE%20%0A%7B%0A%20%20%3Fsancak%20ogp%3AP15%20%3Fstatement.%0A%20%20%3Fstatement%20ogps%3AP15%20og%3AQ4.%0A%20%20%3Fstatement%20ogpq%3AP7%20%3Fstarttime.%0A%20%20%3Fstatement%20ogpq%3AP34%20%3Fvilayet.%0A%20%20%3Fsancak%20ogt%3AP14%20%3FsancakSeat.%0A%20%20%3FsancakSeat%20ogt%3AP10%20%3Fcoord.%0A%20%20OPTIONAL%7B%3Fstatement%20ogpq%3AP8%20%3Fendtime.%7D%0A%20%20OPTIONAL%7B%3Fstatement%20ogpq%3AP22%20%3Fendtime.%7D%0A%20%20%3FsancakSeat%20rdfs%3Alabel%20%3FsancakSeat_ota%20filter%20%28lang%28%3FsancakSeat_ota%29%20%3D%20%22ota%22%29%0A%20%20%23enter%20same%20year%20twice%0A%20%20FILTER%28YEAR%28%3Fstarttime%29%20%3C%3D%201900%20%26%26%20YEAR%28%3Fendtime%29%20%3E%201900%29%0A%20%20SERVICE%20wikibase%3Alabel%20%7B%20bd%3AserviceParam%20wikibase%3Alanguage%20%22%5BAUTO_LANGUAGE%5D%2Cen%22%20%7D%0A%7D) and another that works for the [districts](https://ottgaz.org/query/index.html#%23%20Map%20of%20every%20kaza%20seat%20within%20each%20vilayet%2C%20in%20the%20year%201900.%20Labels%20in%20Ottoman%20Turkish.%20To%20search%20a%20different%20year%2C%20change%20both%20dates%20in%20line%2024.%0A%23defaultView%3AMap%7B%22layer%22%3A%22%3Fvilayet2Label%22%2C%22hide%22%3A%22%3Fcoord%22%7D%0APREFIX%20og%3A%20%3Chttps%3A%2F%2Fottgaz.org%2Fentity%2F%3E%0APREFIX%20ogs%3A%20%3Chttps%3A%2F%2Fottgaz.org%2Fentity%2Fstatement%2F%3E%0APREFIX%20ogv%3A%20%3Chttps%3A%2F%2Fottgaz.org%2Fvalue%2F%3E%0APREFIX%20ogt%3A%20%3Chttps%3A%2F%2Fottgaz.org%2Fprop%2Fdirect%2F%3E%0APREFIX%20ogp%3A%20%3Chttps%3A%2F%2Fottgaz.org%2Fprop%2F%3E%0APREFIX%20ogps%3A%20%3Chttps%3A%2F%2Fottgaz.org%2Fprop%2Fstatement%2F%3E%0APREFIX%20ogpq%3A%20%3Chttps%3A%2F%2Fottgaz.org%2Fprop%2Fqualifier%2F%3E%0A%0ASELECT%20%3Fvilayet2Label%20%3FkazaSeat_ota%20%3FkazaSeat%20%3FkazaCoord%20%3FkazaSeatLabel%0AWHERE%20%0A%7B%20%0A%20%20%20%20%0A%20%20%23%20kazas%0A%20%20%3Fkaza%20ogp%3AP15%20%3Fstatement2.%0A%20%20%3Fstatement2%20ogps%3AP15%20og%3AQ3.%0A%20%20%3Fstatement2%20ogpq%3AP7%20%3Fstarttime2.%0A%20%20%3Fstatement2%20ogpq%3AP34%20%3Fsancak2.%0A%20%20%3Fkaza%20ogt%3AP14%20%3FkazaSeat.%0A%20%20%3FkazaSeat%20ogt%3AP10%20%3FkazaCoord.%0A%20%20OPTIONAL%7B%3Fstatement2%20ogpq%3AP8%20%3Fendtime2.%7D%0A%20%20OPTIONAL%7B%3Fstatement2%20ogpq%3AP22%20%3Fendtime2.%7D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%0A%20%20%23%20find%20vilayets%20for%20kazas%0A%20%20%3Fsancak2%20ogp%3AP15%20%3Fstatement3.%0A%20%20%3Fstatement3%20ogps%3AP15%20og%3AQ4.%0A%20%20%3Fstatement3%20ogpq%3AP7%20%3Fstarttime3.%0A%20%20%3Fstatement3%20ogpq%3AP34%20%3Fvilayet2.%0A%20%20OPTIONAL%7B%3Fstatement3%20ogpq%3AP8%20%3Fendtime3.%7D%0A%20%20OPTIONAL%7B%3Fstatement3%20ogpq%3AP22%20%3Fendtime3.%7D%0A%20%20%20%0A%20%20%23%20get%20ottoman%20label%0A%20%20%3FkazaSeat%20rdfs%3Alabel%20%3FkazaSeat_ota%20filter%20%28lang%28%3FkazaSeat_ota%29%20%3D%20%22ota%22%29%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%0A%20%20%23enter%20same%20year%20twice%0A%20%20FILTER%28YEAR%28%3Fstarttime2%29%20%3C%3D%201900%20%26%26%20YEAR%28%3Fendtime2%29%20%3E%201900%29%0A%20%20FILTER%28YEAR%28%3Fstarttime3%29%20%3C%3D%201900%20%26%26%20YEAR%28%3Fendtime3%29%20%3E%201900%29%0A%20%20SERVICE%20wikibase%3Alabel%20%7B%20bd%3AserviceParam%20wikibase%3Alanguage%20%22%5BAUTO_LANGUAGE%5D%2Cen%22%20%7D%0A%7D), but I can't figure out how to combine them into a single query.

This is what I'm trying (on the [query service of my wikibase](https://ottgaz.org/query/index.html#%23%20Map%20of%20every%20sancak%20and%20kaza%20seat%20within%20each%20vilayet%2C%20in%20the%20year%201900.%20Labels%20in%20Ottoman%20Turkish.%20To%20search%20a%20different%20year%2C%20change%20both%20dates%20in%20lines%2050-52.%0A%23defaultView%3AMap%7B%22layer%22%3A%22%3FvilayetLabel%22%2C%22hide%22%3A%22%3Fcoord%22%7D%0APREFIX%20og%3A%20%3Chttps%3A%2F%2Fottgaz.org%2Fentity%2F%3E%0APREFIX%20ogs%3A%20%3Chttps%3A%2F%2Fottgaz.org%2Fentity%2Fstatement%2F%3E%0APREFIX%20ogv%3A%20%3Chttps%3A%2F%2Fottgaz.org%2Fvalue%2F%3E%0APREFIX%20ogt%3A%20%3Chttps%3A%2F%2Fottgaz.org%2Fprop%2Fdirect%2F%3E%0APREFIX%20ogp%3A%20%3Chttps%3A%2F%2Fottgaz.org%2Fprop%2F%3E%0APREFIX%20ogps%3A%20%3Chttps%3A%2F%2Fottgaz.org%2Fprop%2Fstatement%2F%3E%0APREFIX%20ogpq%3A%20%3Chttps%3A%2F%2Fottgaz.org%2Fprop%2Fqualifier%2F%3E%0A%0ASELECT%20%3FvilayetLabel%20%3Fseat_ota%20%3Fseat%20%3Fcoord%20%3FseatLabel%0AWHERE%20%0A%7B%20%0A%20%20%23%20sancaks%0A%20%20%3Fsancak%20ogp%3AP15%20%3Fstatement.%0A%20%20%3Fstatement%20ogps%3AP15%20og%3AQ4.%0A%20%20%3Fstatement%20ogpq%3AP7%20%3Fstarttime.%0A%20%20%3Fstatement%20ogpq%3AP34%20%3Fvilayet1.%0A%20%20%3Fsancak%20ogt%3AP14%20%3FsancakSeat.%0A%20%20%3FsancakSeat%20ogt%3AP10%20%3Fcoord.%0A%20%20OPTIONAL%7B%3Fstatement%20ogpq%3AP8%20%3Fendtime.%7D%0A%20%20OPTIONAL%7B%3Fstatement%20ogpq%3AP22%20%3Fendtime.%7D%0A%20%20%0A%20%20%23%20kazas%0A%20%20%3Fkaza%20ogp%3AP15%20%3Fstatement2.%0A%20%20%3Fstatement2%20ogps%3AP15%20og%3AQ3.%0A%20%20%3Fstatement2%20ogpq%3AP7%20%3Fstarttime2.%0A%20%20%3Fstatement2%20ogpq%3AP34%20%3Fsancak2.%0A%20%20%3Fkaza%20ogt%3AP14%20%3FkazaSeat.%0A%20%20%3FkazaSeat%20ogt%3AP10%20%3FkazaCoord.%0A%20%20OPTIONAL%7B%3Fstatement2%20ogpq%3AP8%20%3Fendtime2.%7D%0A%20%20OPTIONAL%7B%3Fstatement2%20ogpq%3AP22%20%3Fendtime2.%7D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%0A%20%20%23%20find%20vilayets%20for%20kazas%0A%20%20%3Fsancak2%20ogp%3AP15%20%3Fstatement3.%0A%20%20%3Fstatement3%20ogps%3AP15%20og%3AQ4.%0A%20%20%3Fstatement3%20ogpq%3AP7%20%3Fstarttime3.%0A%20%20%3Fstatement3%20ogpq%3AP34%20%3Fvilayet2.%0A%20%20OPTIONAL%7B%3Fstatement3%20ogpq%3AP8%20%3Fendtime3.%7D%0A%20%20OPTIONAL%7B%3Fstatement3%20ogpq%3AP22%20%3Fendtime3.%7D%0A%20%20%0A%20%20%23%20combine%20vilayets%2C%20seats%0A%20%20BIND%20%28%20CONCAT%28%3Fvilayet1%2C%20%3Fvilayet2%29%20AS%20%3Fvilayet%29%0A%20%20BIND%20%28%20CONCAT%28%3FkazaSeat%2C%20%3FsancakSeat%29%20AS%20%3Fseat%29%0A%20%20%0A%20%20%23%20get%20ottoman%20label%0A%20%20%3Fseat%20rdfs%3Alabel%20%3Fseat_ota%20filter%20%28lang%28%3Fseat_ota%29%20%3D%20%22ota%22%29%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%0A%20%20%23enter%20same%20year%20twice%0A%20%20FILTER%28YEAR%28%3Fstarttime%29%20%3C%3D%201900%20%26%26%20YEAR%28%3Fendtime%29%20%3E%201900%29%0A%20%20FILTER%28YEAR%28%3Fstarttime2%29%20%3C%3D%201900%20%26%26%20YEAR%28%3Fendtime2%29%20%3E%201900%29%0A%20%20FILTER%28YEAR%28%3Fstarttime3%29%20%3C%3D%201900%20%26%26%20YEAR%28%3Fendtime3%29%20%3E%201900%29%0A%20%20SERVICE%20wikibase%3Alabel%20%7B%20bd%3AserviceParam%20wikibase%3Alanguage%20%22%5BAUTO_LANGUAGE%5D%2Cen%22%20%7D%0A%7D)). Basically it runs the two queries that I know work in parallel, then attempts to bind the `?vilayet` and `?seat` results from each :

```
# Map of every sancak and kaza seat within each vilayet, in the year 1900. Labels in Ottoman Turkish. To search a different year, change both dates in lines 50-52.
#defaultView:Map{"layer":"?vilayetLabel","hide":"?coord"}
PREFIX og: <https://ottgaz.org/entity/>
PREFIX ogs: <https://ottgaz.org/entity/statement/>
PREFIX ogv: <https://ottgaz.org/value/>
PREFIX ogt: <https://ottgaz.org/prop/direct/>
PREFIX ogp: <https://ottgaz.org/prop/>
PREFIX ogps: <https://ottgaz.org/prop/statement/>
PREFIX ogpq: <https://ottgaz.org/prop/qualifier/>

SELECT ?vilayetLabel ?seat_ota ?seat ?coord ?seatLabel
WHERE 
{ 
  # sancaks
  ?sancak ogp:P15 ?statement.
  ?statement ogps:P15 og:Q4.
  ?statement ogpq:P7 ?starttime.
  ?statement ogpq:P34 ?vilayet1.
  ?sancak ogt:P14 ?sancakSeat.
  ?sancakSeat ogt:P10 ?coord.
  OPTIONAL{?statement ogpq:P8 ?endtime.}
  OPTIONAL{?statement ogpq:P22 ?endtime.}
  
  # kazas
  ?kaza ogp:P15 ?statement2.
  ?statement2 ogps:P15 og:Q3.
  ?statement2 ogpq:P7 ?starttime2.
  ?statement2 ogpq:P34 ?sancak2.
  ?kaza ogt:P14 ?kazaSeat.
  ?kazaSeat ogt:P10 ?kazaCoord.
  OPTIONAL{?statement2 ogpq:P8 ?endtime2.}
  OPTIONAL{?statement2 ogpq:P22 ?endtime2.}
            
  # find vilayets for kazas
  ?sancak2 ogp:P15 ?statement3.
  ?statement3 ogps:P15 og:Q4.
  ?statement3 ogpq:P7 ?starttime3.
  ?statement3 ogpq:P34 ?vilayet2.
  OPTIONAL{?statement3 ogpq:P8 ?endtime3.}
  OPTIONAL{?statement3 ogpq:P22 ?endtime3.}
  
  # combine vilayets, seats
  BIND ( CONCAT(?vilayet1, ?vilayet2) AS ?vilayet)
  BIND ( CONCAT(?kazaSeat, ?sancakSeat) AS ?seat)
  
  # get ottoman label
  ?seat rdfs:label ?seat_ota filter (lang(?seat_ota) = "ota")
            
  #enter same year twice
  FILTER(YEAR(?starttime) <= 1900 && YEAR(?endtime) > 1900)
  FILTER(YEAR(?starttime2) <= 1900 && YEAR(?endtime2) > 1900)
  FILTER(YEAR(?starttime3) <= 1900 && YEAR(?endtime3) > 1900)
  SERVICE wikibase:label { bd:serviceParam wikibase:language "[AUTO_LANGUAGE],en" }
}
```

It returns an "unknown error," and I can't figure out why. The queries are a bit intricate, because they involve qualifiers. Maybe I'm not binding or concatenating correctly?

Comment: Your query does a cross-join on the bindings  - is this intended? I mean, you have bindings for the "sancak" and "kaza", but how are they connected? what is the purpose of your query? Shouldn't you use a join on the "vilayet" such that you're referring to the same "vilayet" in each row?